# How to resolve "HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length." in java

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection

I am using HttpConnect and trying to get some token from the server. But whenever I try to get the response, its always saying you have not set or problem with content length even I tried to set the content length in many different ways

```
conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod(method);
conn.setRequestProperty("X-DocuSign-Authentication", httpAuthHeader);
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
if (method.equalsIgnoreCase("POST")) {
  conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(body.length()));
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
}


status = conn.getResponseCode(); // triggers the request
if (status != 200) { //// 200 = OK 
    errorParse(conn, status);
    return;
}

InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
```

Comment: But if I try to do the same thing using HttpClient its working.

Comment: HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

Comment: What methods are you using. This should happen for PUT. Changing `if (method.equalsIgnoreCase("POST")) ` to check for PUT might solve your problem

Comment: @AniruddhaDas Then you aren't doing the same thing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Moving away from `HttpConnect` to `HttpClient` worked for me. So I moved away from `HttpURLConnection` and created an http `HttpClient` object and call execute methods to get data from the server.

Below is the code which make http request using `HttpClient` rather `HttpURLConnection`

```
try {
  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(authUrl);
  String json = "";
  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
  jsonObject.accumulate("phone", "phone");
  json = jsonObject.toString();
  StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
  httpPost.setEntity(se);

  httpPost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
  httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

  // 9. receive response as inputStream
  inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
  String response = getResponseBody(inputStream);

  System.out.println(response);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
  System.out.println("ClientProtocolException : " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("IOException:" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Exception:" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

Comment: The essence here is that you moved away from setting an explicit `Content-length`. Any suggestion or illusion that `HttpURLConnection` doesn't work is baseless. Why it took you eighteen months after I had already told you the answer is a mystery. I don't know why people post questions here if they're not going to take any notice of the answers they get.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting a content-length but never sending a request body.

*Don't* set the content-length. Java does it for you.

NB `setDoOutput(true)` sets the method to POST.

Comment: I tried with that as well but it did not work. Actually I am sending a string to docusign server and expecting a token from them. I am trying to implement this:  https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/OAuth2/OAuth2%20Token%20Request.htm

Comment: You tried what? If you're doing a POST, you need to send something. You're not. Your `HttpClient` code does, and that's why it works.

Comment: it did not worked for me. the other way I posted in my answer worked for me. it looks like HttpGet/HttpPost methods worked well for docusign and eOriginal

Comment: @AniruddhaDas The answer you posted doesn't contain a content-length, which is exactly what this answer says too.